# Progressbar graphic bug?

Tags: android

Can someone please explain why my progressbar isnt a straight line (pic below)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25px"
    android:progress="50"
/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What's your device model and Android Version?

Comment: @PierreRymiortz Samsung Galaxy S2, 4.03

Comment: Thanks. Did you try using dip instead of px for the ProgressBar height? Px shouldn't be used in layouts, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: @PierreRymiortz Yes I'm afraid I tried all three units. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You set:

```
android:layout_height="25px"
```

which means 25 pixels, which is usually less than 3 millimiters in most devices.

Ex:

Screen with 800 pixel and 8 cm -> 8 / 800 = 0.01 cm = 0.1 mm
25 pixel = 2.5 millimiters

Regards.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? Another unit? Would it mattter if its less than 3mm?

Comment: Johan, I'm sorry. I misundertood it. I read `is` instead of `isnt`. I can't really see any curve, with exception of a pixel that looks odd in the end. Is that? Are you using `rotation()` or `Matrix`?

Comment: Np. I dont think I'm using neither nor. How would I know that?